# How to make an In memory Database using Web SQL database and Rails or ElasticSearch and Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, browser-cache, web-sql, in-memory-database

I have a rails website, where I want to pre-filter the comments of Abusive words.

For that if I create the in-memory database in browser, I will be able to populate it with the list of abusive words, which a user cannot use in comments.

But I don't know how to go ahead with it in Mysql and I don't know how to create an In-memory database of the Browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a bit vague as it currently stands. For example do you want to filter client side or server side? What is the relevance of elasticsearch (mentioned only in the title)?

Comment: I want the comments to be filtered automatically when the user writes comment, before posting it, the database checks with the words which are not to be used. For that, I have these two ways of doing it. 1 - Use browser local storage to populate words when the user visits the website. 2- Store those words in database as a string, match it real time with the words used by the user.